# Unable to use static getDerivedStateFromProps inside Redux + Typescript Connected Component

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, getderivedstatefromprops

I am unable to use `static` method inside Class Component which is Connected to Redux. TypeScript reports

```
Argument of type 'typeof SAI' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<IStateProps & IDispatchProps>'.
  Type 'typeof SAI' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<IStateProps & IDispatchProps>'.
    Type 'typeof SAI' provides no match for the signature '(props: IStateProps & IDispatchProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

Container:

```
export interface IStateProps {
  saiList: ISaiList
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IRootState) => ({
  saiList: SaiListSelector(state)
});

export interface IDispatchProps {
  getSai: () => Dispatch<AnyAction>;
  postSai: (saiList: ISaiList) => Dispatch<AnyAction>;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  getSai: () => dispatch<any>(getSaiList()),
  postSai: (saiList: ISaiList) => dispatch<any>(postSaiList(saiList))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SAI);
```

Component part:

```
interface ISAIState {
  editActive: boolean;
  localSai: ISaiList;
  sortBy: string;
}

type ISaiProps = IStateProps & IDispatchProps;

export default class SAI extends React.Component<ISaiProps> {

  public state: ISAIState = {
    editActive: false,
    localSai: [...this.props.saiList],
    sortBy: 'default'
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: ISaiProps, state: ISAIState) {
    window.console.log(props, state);
  }
```

Is this an issue with `@types/react-redux` being not up-to-date or is it something from my side? When I comment out

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: ISaiProps, state: ISAIState) {
    window.console.log(props, state);
}
```

method, all works ok...

Comment: Was you able to fix this issue? if so, share solution pls, i am stuck with this problem

Comment: Yep, be sure to return plain object :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `getDerivedStateFromProps` expects an object to be returned.

[From the official documentation:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.